# C++ / C call method from running software

Tags: c++, c, google-chrome, plugins, google-nativeclient

I would like to use C++ / C to call a method of an running application. So it should work the following way:

An application is running, let's say Chrome and another application is running (plugin.exe). The other application should call a Chrome c++ method from the outside. Is that possible?

The method that I would like to call is the method displaying auto suggests. I would like to develop an omnibox with multiple keywords.

Somehow I would like to hook into the application and send / receive events and call methods. I guess event reeving can be done, since it's possible to use the Microsoft debugger with an executable and catch a lot of events.

While researching a bit I found out how to load a dll plugin in Chrome:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi

I've done the same in Pepper API as well, but from there I can't reach any further.

Comment: any sample would be appreciated

Comment: You cannot hook into omnibar for obvious security reasons: imagine if a plugin could replace the URL you are typing with a malicious one. Also, calling a C++/C method from outside the running program is actually tricky because you are not aware of the internal status. The other way round should be straightforward (i.e. having Chrome call your library functions).